# The definition of simultaneous conjugacy class

Tags: group-theory, terminology

I would like to know the definition of "simultaneous conjugacy class". I have found this concept in "Compact connected Lie transformation groups of spheres with low cohomogeneity".

Answer (score 0):

It's the equivalence classes under simultaneous conjugacy. Formally, the simultaneous conjugacy classes of $n$-tuples of elements of a group $G$ consist of the orbits of the action of $G$ acting on $G^n$ by simutaneous conjugation:

$$g(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n) = (gx_1 g^{-1}, gx_2 g^{-1}, \dots gx_n g^{-1}).$$

These can be interpreted topologically as the isomorphism classes of $G$-local systems on the wedge of $n$ circles.